# How do I transfer photos from Samsung SGH-T139 cell phone to Win 7 PC?

Tags: photos, transfer

I have a Samsung SGH-T139 cell phone, and this phone has photos in it. I'm interested in copying these photos from my phone to my Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) PC.

My phone plan is the T-Mobile "Pay As You Go" plan, which does not include data. Thus, I am not able to send these photos to my email address as picture messages.

I purchased the Samsung SGH-T139 Data Transfer Sync Cable (https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0ZA-002Z-06B92), and I installed the Samsung PC Studio 3.2.3 software (http://samsung-pc-studio.en.lo4d.com/) onto my PC. I read somewhere that, if I installed the software onto my PC and connected the phone to the PC via the cable, then I would be able to transfer the photos from the phone to the PC. Unfortunately, the software is not able to connect to the phone.

So, how do I get the software to recognize the phone? Is there any way to transfer the photos from the phone to the PC, except sending picture messages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the internet seems to think this isn't possible:

> "The Samsung SGH-T139 does not have the ability to transfer pictures using a data cable or memory card."

Furthermore, there seemed to be at least one review for a cable where the specific complaint was that the cable did not allow data transfers as advertised.

In short, it seems very likely that you will have to shell out for data and use the email option.

Comment: It appears that the SGH-T139 has bluetooth. At my home, I have a desktop (HP Pavilion Elite HPE-250f) and a laptop (HP G62 Notebook). If I attach a Bluetooth USB dongle to the desktop or the laptop, will I be able to transfer the photos from the SGH-T139 to the desktop or the laptop via Bluetooth?

Comment: You could try. However, [T-Mobile makes no mention of data support](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-8415). The primary purpose of the Bluetooth connection seems to be to pair with Bluetooth-enabled headsets or similar.